# Fast system shutdown in Python

Tags: python, shutdown, system-shutdown

I'm designing a piece of electronic hardware that may come into contact with water if there is a mechanical malfunction (e.g. a seal breaks). Inside the device, I have moisture sensors around all critical areas. I've already written a script that monitors these moisture sensors, but I want to write an emergency script that if any of the moisture sensors sense water, the system can be shut off quickly to avoid electrical damage to the device itself and anyone/anything nearby.

At the moment, all I was able to find was the following protocol:

```
import os
os.system('shutdown -P now')
```

Is there a trivial way of making the computer have a 'hard' shut down?

I've also considered having the main power be fed to the device through a relay that the computer can control so I can just physically cut power to the computer, but I was hoping there was a way to do this without having to use such a heavy duty power relay.

Comment: You mean shutdown -h now

Comment: Assuming this is Linux, you probably want to use `poweroff -f`. Better yet, find the source code for that utility and figure out how to invoke the system call directly from Python...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! What are the differences between -P,  -h , and power off -f? I'm very new to coding in python for hardware applications so my knowledge is very limited.

Comment: After running the script does the pc shutdown? If not you will need sudo permissions to run it.

Comment: @mwweb, yes, the system does shut down. The script runs with the right privileges. I'm just wondering if there's a quicker way to shut down in an emergency scenario.

Comment: yes there are other faster options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using System Request (SysRq) and than calling `echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger` to immediately reboot the system, without unmounting or syncing filesystems.

```
import os

os.system('echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq && echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger')
```

Check this answer for more info:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163370/is-there-a-fastest-way-to-shutdown-the-system

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import os
os.system('shutdown -h now')
```

Comment: Does the -h mean 'hard shutdown'?

Comment: Means shutdown and halt, by passing `now`, it will shutdown immediately.
[See this post](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ushutdow.htm), may it will be helpful.

Comment: Have you try to perform some virtual tests in a closed envirionment, with a virtual software or something like this?

Comment: Thanks @Abe ! That post was very helpful. And yes, I have a VM that I've been testing on and the current code I have works and shuts down the system. I've also tested this on the actual device that this is to be used on. It works just fine, but I want the fastest option available because I want this specific code to be used in an emergency situation. I guess I can time all the options and find the fastest one, but I was hoping there was an obvious solution before I did all that.